# Set position of div dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to create a search result box. Whenever a user type something in the search text box the list of result will be populated in the search result box just underneath the textbox. I am able to do this where there is only one instance of the search box(the caller is a single textbox). The problem occurs when the same searchbox is used for multiple text boxes. I want it to adjust its position according to the caller textbox. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .searchDiv {
            border: 1px solid red;
            width:150px;
            height:100px;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        showSearchBox = function (_element) {
            var _div = document.getElementById('divSearch');
            _div.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        hideSearchBox = function () {           
            var _div = document.getElementById('divSearch');
            _div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" style="width: 50%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 50%">
                    <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" onfocus="showSearchBox(this)" onblur="hideSearchBox()" />
                </td>
                <td style="width: 50%">
                    <input type="text" id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" onfocus="showSearchBox(this)" onblur="hideSearchBox()"/>
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="width: 100%">
                    This is just a placeholder text.
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <div id="divSearch" class="searchDiv"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

What changes do I need to make in my code? You can also check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rms2L438/)

Comment: Is jQuery an option? Use classes instead of ID for multiple elements.

Comment: It's legacy code but yes, if jQuery can solve the problem I will be happy to implement it. The fiddle is just a sample code as the original code is very messy.

Comment: Is use of table is compulsory? Can not move div from one  td to another.

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia: Yes. I can not play with the existing HTML. Will increase the work a lot. I need to do that using javascript. The solution is to adjust the coordinates using javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this to your show div method. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rms2L438/2/). to make it more general you can use the top and left values from parent. Also add `position:relative` to your div

```
 var parentPositionLeft = _element.getBoundingClientRect().left;
 var parentPositionTop = _element.getBoundingClientRect().top;


            _div.style.left = parentPositionLeft+'px';
            _div.style.top = parentPositionTop+'px';
            console.log(_div.style.left);
```

Comment: Superb. Just had to add this in the css: position: absolute and could also set the top position. Sweet and precise.

Comment: yes missed that. thanks for pointing out i will update the answer also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to modify the position of .searchDiv.

```
$(".searchDiv").css({top: 55, left: 220, position:'absolute'});
```

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/ybdesire/yy751fn6/

Comment: Simple and perfect. In my case I had to include a `#` in the `div` name. How, `$("#Div_name").css({ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have plain javascript, so in this case you gonna need to change your function `showSearchBox` function like this:

```
showSearchBox = function (_element) {
    var _div = document.getElementById('divSearch');

    var input = _element.getBoundingClientRect();

    _div.style.left = input.left + 'px';
    _div.style.top = input.top + 'px';
    _div.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

and add this rule to you css class `.searchDiv`:

```
position: relative;
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rms2L438/3/)

Comment: Doesn't work. What if one textbox is at the top left and the other one is at the bottom right of the screen? That is what required. The search box must maintain its position as per the position of the calling element.

Comment: I have updated fiddle, try if this fits your problem requirements

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find out the exact position of the textbox where it is placed
then placed this Div with postion absolute occordingly to that position below or above